# Existence of projection-like operator

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $S$ be a vector space, and let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of equal dimension. If $\lbrace u_i\rbrace$ and $\lbrace w_i\rbrace$ are bases for $U$ and $W$ respectively, show that there exists an operator $A$ such that 
\begin{align*}
Au_i &= w_i \\
Av &= 0\ \ \ \mbox{ for all }\ \ \ v \in U^\perp  
\end{align*}

I know how I would construct an operator that projects an arbitrary vector $x \in S$ on to $W$, but I don't know how to restrict only to vectors in $U$ while sending the rest to zero. Also, I am curious how you would construct such an operator in practice.

Comment: Construct a basis for $U^\perp$; the union of that basis with the basis you have for $U$ is a basis for $S$; define $A$ on this basis for $S$ in the appropriate way; extend $A$ to all of $S$ by linearity; done!

Comment: Thanks!  So is it as simple as the following? 

If $u_1,..,u_k$ is a basis for $U$ and $u_{k+1},...,u_n$ is a basis for $U^\perp$, then 
$A[\vec{u}_1,...,\vec{u}_k,\vec{u}_{k+1},...,\vec{u}_n] = [\vec{w}_1,...,\vec{w}_k,\vec{0},...,\vec{0}]$
And then we just multiply both sides by $[\vec{u}_1,...,\vec{u}_n]^{-1}$?

Also, is there a particular name for this kind of transformation?

Comment: I don't know what you achieve by multiplying by that inverse (and that inverse only makes sense after you've chosen a basis for $S$).

Comment: By right multiplying both sides by that inverse, I get the matrix A which sends vectors $\vec{u}_1,...,\vec{u}_k$ to $\vec{w}_1,...,\vec{w}_k$ respectively, and the rest to zero. However, there is a problem I'm encountering, which is that $A(\vec{u}_1+\vec{u}_n)$ will be nonzero, even though that is outside the subspace $U$.

Comment: Are you confusing the complement of $U$ and the orthogonal complement of $U$? There is no way to make a linear transformation be zero on the complement of a subspace (without making it identically zero, that is).

Comment: Aaaaaah! Yes I think I confused the complement with the orthogonal complement. That really clears things up, thanks.

Comment: Good. So now maybe you can write up and post an answer.